# Converting array back to a jQuery set

Tags: javascript, jquery

I needed to convert a jQuery set to an array to use array methods like `sort` and `map`:

```
const result = $('.selector').toArray().map(function (el) {
    const o = $(el);
    return {object: o, value: o.data('value')};
}).sort(function (a, b) {
    if (a.value > b.value) return 1;
    if (a.value < b.value) return -1;
    return 0;
}).map(el => el.object);
```

As you can see the result is an array of jQuery objects.

Now I need to convert that back to a jQuery set in order to manipulate it:

```
$(result).appendTo('#main');
```

But `$(result)` does not quite look like `$('.selector)` and I am getting the following error:

```
TypeError: e is undefined
```

Comment: `result` is an array. Do you need to append all the `result` items to '#main'? Also, `object: e` seems incorrect to me. Shouldn't it be `object: el`?

Comment: You might want to loop through `result` instead. Like briosheje mentioned, it's an array. You are not supposed to use an array as selector for jQuery.

Comment: Try `$('#main').append(result);` instead.

Comment: @briosheje `result` is an array but I am passing it to `$` to convert it back to a jQuery object. Yes, I need to append `result` to `#main` but I need to further maniuplate those `result` elements with jQuery methods. `object: e` was typo; fixed it now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of using `appendTo`, I would rather use `append` that, as you can see in the docs, in its signature, accepts an array as well: http://api.jquery.com/append/

> htmlString or Element or Text or Array or jQuery DOM
>   element, text node, **array of elements and text nodes**, HTML string, or
>   jQuery object to insert at the end of each element in the set of
>   matched elements.

So, instead of: `$(result).appendTo('#main');`, just use:

```
$('#main').append(result);
```

as long as `result` is an array of any of the above supported types.

Comment: As I said I my comment, I need to keep manipulating `$(result)` as a jQuery object. Appending it to `#main` is not the only thing I need to do.

Comment: You can't manipulate the single object, you need to manipulate the entire array. Can you please give an example of further manipulations you need to do?

Comment: Actually all I needed to do was to iterate it with `each` but I can easily turn that one into a `for` loop since it's now an array. I just wondered if there was a way to reverse `$('.selector').toArray()` back to a jQuery set object.

Comment: That's what I told you in the comment below your question @dabadaba

Comment: @dabadaba Well you can either loop with a for loop, or, just use `$('.selector')` again. jQuery's set object is just a DOM selector, nothing more than that.

Comment: Yes but `$('.selector')` adds some overhead I'd rather not have. That was my point of reusing the array.

Comment: @dabadaba I think you should give us another example on how you need to further manipulate the array, otherwise it's quite hard to optimize it, I think there are some ways to come back to a DOM selector from an array, but I would bet they're **not** more efficient than just reusing the selector.